# Arcanist Dimensional Slide usage specific cases!

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, teleportation, arcanist

So here it goes.

Description says that:

> The arcanist can expend 1 point from her arcane reservoir to create a
>   dimensional crack that she can step through to reach another location.
>   This ability is used as part of a move action or withdraw action,
>   allowing her to move up to 10 feet per arcanist level to any location
>   she can see. This counts as 5 feet of movement. She can only use this
>   ability once per round. She does not provoke attacks of opportunity
>   when moving in this way, but any other movement she attempts as part
>   of her move action provokes as normal.

Here's what is not specified (and what causes my GM to question my way of using this skill):

a) If I can use it anytime movement action is possible can I use it while sitting (to teleport from chair to chair for example) or when lying on the ground?

b) Can I decide whether DS is first or last part of my movement? So for example use it to escape melee combat (avoid AoO) and teleport behind my team? Or do I have to do other movement first (thus inducing AoO) and DS last?

c) Can I open the crack below me so I just fall into it?

d) Can DS be the only movement that I make?

DISCLAIMER: I'm only interested in RAW answers. I'm not interested in house-rules or opinions.

Comment: can you specify what you mean by point 'c'? Fall into it where?

Comment: We operate using a one question-one answer setup. Occasionally, we allow very strongly related questions to coexist, but in cases where the only link is the ability in question, you're better off writing multiple questions. I would recommend 3 questions; you can probably combine "directly under me" with "while sitting or prone".

Comment: Fall into destination. If I can open it in point A to land in point B it shouldn't matter whether I'm walking through crack, being pushed into the crack or fall into the crack.

Comment: @Ifusaso I actually think that this can all be grouped into "what restrictions are there on dimmensional slide?" or something similar. this is all pretty tightly grouped.

Comment: Ifusaso it doesn't get more connected than very tight specifics of a single ability in question. Also what goodguy5 said.

Comment: The underlying question here is asking how Dimensional Slide interacts with movement. These can be grouped together, they don't need to be split into separate questions.

Comment: I disagree... it could be very easy to be correct about whether you can use DS as your only a movement but have the rules wrong about using it while sitting or prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think any of these are edge cases, personally. but...

## This should all be fine.

note: Attacks of opportunity from movement are no generated by the 5 feet "spent" to activate this ability. If an Arcanist runs past an enemy, Dimensional Slides away from a second, and then runs past a third, then the first and third provoke, while the second does not.

Alright, let's list out the requirements to use the ability:

- use a move (or withdraw) action
- have at least 5 feet of movement to use
- have at least 1 arcanist point
- not have used this ability already this round

Cool. Now, we can address your points:

#### Moving from chair to chair should be fine.

The rules about moving while sitting are a little strained, at worst it's the same as the moving while prone rules. So, a DM could make the argument that you'd use extra movement to activate the ability, but I don't think this is supported by RAW.

#### The Dimensional Slide can be any part of the move, as it augments the move.

The ability doesn't specify that a specific timing is required, so as long as you meet the criteria, use 5 feet of movement and slide away; beginning, end, or in between.

#### I guess you can open a crack, thematically, but mechanically there's no difference.

This sounds like a cool description that you're using that has zero mechanical impact. The important thing is that you're meeting the criteria. If your DM is having trouble with this, it might be worth a conversation about "cool descriptors" vs "mechanics". There aren't a lot (if any?) rules to support you backflipping over your enemy's arrow, grabbing it, and stabbing them with it; but as a descriptor for missile reflection, it works.

#### You are not required to use your full movement when moving, even with Dimensional Slide.

As long as you meet those criteria, you can use a move action, spend an arcanist point, and Slide for the cost of 5 feet of movement. There is no obligation to use more movement.

---

In response to my self-prompted question "What restrictions are there on Dimensional Slide?"

#### As long as there isn't anything preventing movement (and you meet the criteria I mentioned), you should be able to use Dimensional Slide.

If someone, such as a DM, is hung up on the words "step through", Pathfinder doesn't describe what a "Step" means; it does however define the mechanical implications of the ability, which is what should (and must, in my opinion) be used to determine validity of usage.

Comment: Just to clarify: In all of those cases AoO doesn't apply unless AFTER the teleport I start moving in some creature's zone of AoO right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I will add a line to see if that answers you.

Comment: Please also clarify whether DS from sitting or lying on the ground (or any other strange position for that matter) would provoke AoO for the sake of completeness and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: @NecXelos Could you please explain how my note does not cover this case? The movement from Dimensional Slide does not provoke AoO

Comment: I would argue that moving from one chair to another isn't "part of a move action" and is not a valid use of the ability. At the least (if it mattered enough to go into rounds) standing up, moving to another chair, and sitting in that one would be 2 *free actions* and a move action (potentially a free action and 2 move actions if your GM rules a worst case scenario and considers the chair as you being prone)

Comment: @Ifusaso if "sitting" counts as "prone", then you could just crawl, using movement.

Comment: Also getting up from prone is a movement action itself so if You can move You can DS.

Comment: @goodguy5 Sitting and kneeling don't count as prone; they provide a +2 AC vs ranged and a -2 AC vs melee (similar to but half of being prone) and there [doesn't seem to be rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158264/how-do-i-sit-down-or-stand-up) about how you get to or out of that postition

Answer (score -4):

I thought I will chime in for clarity. The main problem here is whether you can use DS without provoking an AoO in two situations:

1. Caster is prone/sitting or has their movement otherwise impaired (like being in difficult terrain)
2. Standing next to a mob.

My own opinion is NO to situation 1 and YES to situation 2 provided they take a Withdraw action.

Comment: The text of the ability includes 'She does not provoke attacks of opportunity when moving in this way, but any other movement she attempts as part of her move action provokes as normal.'...clearly it doesn't provoke.